# Spring Security with Backbone URLs

Tags: spring, security, backbone.js

I have a single page application and i want to use spring security. 
In spring-security.xml file, i must give a url to prevent a user.

For example:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/#cities" access="isAuthenticated"/>
```

After this configuration when i try to enter without authentication

```
"localhost:8082/project_name/#cities"
```

It isn't preventing me. I can access the page.

I think, it happens because of that the URL is not real URL. There is only one page. (index.html)

How can i solve this problem? I am sorry about my bad english. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot secure Routes on the back end, as nothing after the # sign in a URL is ever sent up to the server.  You can secure PAGES and ajax endpoints, but you can't secure Routes (the thing after the hash #).

In your sample url there, you can only secure the /project_name part of the URL.  If you don't want people to access the /project_name/#cities, then you'll need to make that a different page.

If you want to secure the #cities views, you'll need to either stop that module from rendering to the client (make sure the .js file that contains the #cities code doesn't get sent down), or you could make it so the #cities views have to retrieve data and secure the ajax endpoints instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

So can you give me an advice about session management in Backbone Single Page App?